# I have a problem with implementing Video call with WebRTC peer connection

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

```
import {
    mediaDevices,
    RTCPeerConnection,
    RTCView,
    RTCIceCandidate,
    RTCSessionDescription,
    MediaStream,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

import styles from './callPageStyle';
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const CallPage = ({ route, navigation }) => {

// const navigation = useNavigation();
const userData = useSelector((state) => state.userData);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const { callerId, calleeId, calleeName, isVideo, isCreator } = route.params;

const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState(null);
const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);
const [callStarted, setCallStarted] = useState(false);
const peerConnectionRef = useRef(null);
const remoteRTCMessage = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const recipientID = isCreator ? calleeId : callerId;
    webSocketService.registerSendCallMessageCallback(recipientID, onNewCall);
    webSocketService.registerAnswerCallMessageCallback(recipientID, onCallAnswered);
    webSocketService.registerICECandidateMessageCallback(recipientID, onICEcandidate);

    const initLocalStream = async () => {
        const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
        setLocalStream(stream);
    };

    const delayProcessCall = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!isCreator) {
            startCall();
        } else {
            initLocalStream();
        }
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(delayProcessCall);

        if (localStream) {
            localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
        }
    };
}, []);


const createPeerConnection = async () => {
    const configuration = {
      iceServers: [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
      ],
    };
    const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  
    // Use a promise to wait for getUserMedia to complete
    const stream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));
    setLocalStream(stream);
  
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
            if (event.candidate) {
            webSocketService.sendICECandidateToPeerServer(userData.id, isCreator ? calleeId : callerId, {
                calleeId: isCreator ? calleeId : callerId,
                rtcMessage: {
                label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: event.candidate.candidate,
                },
            });
            } else {
                console.log("End of candidates.");
            }
        };
    
        peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
            setRemoteStream(event.streams[0]);
        };
    
        peerConnectionRef.current = peerConnection;
        resolve();
    });
};

const startCall = async () => {    
    try {
        console.log("=========sendNewCallToPeerServer===========");
        await createPeerConnection();

        const offer = await peerConnectionRef.current.createOffer();
        await peerConnectionRef.current.setLocalDescription(offer);

        webSocketService.sendNewCallToPeerServer(userData.id, isCreator ? calleeId : callerId, {
            calleeId: isCreator ? calleeId : callerId,
            rtcMessage: offer,
        });

        console.log("=========sendNewCallToPeerServer===========");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating offer:', error);
    }
};

const handleAnswer = async () => {    
    try {
        const answer = await peerConnectionRef.current.createAnswer();
        await peerConnectionRef.current.setLocalDescription(answer);

        webSocketService.sendAnswerCallToPeerServer(userData.id, isCreator ? calleeId : callerId, {
            calleeId: isCreator ? calleeId : callerId,
            rtcMessage: answer,
        });

        setCallStarted(true);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating answer:', error);
    }
};

const onNewCall = async (payload) => {
    console.log("On New Call !!!");
    const bigData = JSON.parse(payload.body);
    const data = JSON.parse(bigData.data);

    remoteRTCMessage.current = data.rtcMessage;

    await createPeerConnection();
    peerConnectionRef.current.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(remoteRTCMessage.current)
    );

    handleAnswer();
};

const onCallAnswered = (payload) => {
    console.log("onCallAnswered !!!");
    const bigData = JSON.parse(payload.body);
    const data = JSON.parse(bigData.data);
    
    remoteRTCMessage.current = data.rtcMessage;
    peerConnectionRef.current.setRemoteDescription(
        new RTCSessionDescription(remoteRTCMessage.current)
    );

    setCallStarted(true);
};

const onICEcandidate = (payload) => {
    console.log("onICEcandidate !!!");
    const bigData = JSON.parse(payload.body);
    const data = JSON.parse(bigData.data);

    let message = data.rtcMessage;

    if (peerConnectionRef.current) {
        peerConnectionRef.current
        .addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate({candidate: message.candidate, sdpMLineIndex: message.label, sdpMid: message.id}))
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error", err);
        });
    }
};
```

This is my source code implementing video call feature in react-native expo app.

I am currently using libraries for react-native-webrtc below.

`@config-plugins/react-native-webrtc": "^7.0.0`

`react-native-webrtc": "^111.0.3`,

I am using Android emulator like this:

- API level 34
- image: system-images/android-34/google_apis/x86_x64

All the logic for getting connection between peers is working well. But have problems with video streaming.
Help me with correcting the source code or giving any advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced that kind of problem before.
Implementing Video call wit WebRTC streaming contains such a complex process.
There is more easier way implementing video call without using basic libraries.
I suggest to use 'agora-rn-uikit' library in React Native.

More details instructions here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-rn-uikit

Installation Command:

```
npm i react-native-agora agora-react-native-rtm agora-rn-uikit
```

Sample Code:

```
const connectionData = {
    appId: '<Agora App ID>',
    channel: 'test',
};
const rtcCallbacks = {
    EndCall: () => setVideoCall(false),
};

<AgoraUIKit connectionData={connectionData} rtcCallbacks={rtcCallbacks} />
```

Easy to use and faster development speed.